# nginx configuration for spring boot and angular project

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, docker, nginx

I am trying to create a app using mongodb and spring-boot as backend and angular as frontend.

Using command to run my app:

```
docker run -d -e APP_OPTIONS="--spring.data.mongodb.host=172.17.0.2" -p 8443:8443 my-webapp
```

I am able to launch my app at `http://localhost/api/swagger-ui.html` successfully(I have configured swagger for backend). Using `server.port=8443` and `server.servlet.context-path=/api`. I am also able to add/update data to mangodb from swagger APIs.

My frontend is in angular and using a proxy.config.json file to connect to backend:

```
{
"/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8443/",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
   }
}
```

Also using `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json` command, I am able to launch angular UI and able to fetch data from database/backend successfully.

The problem arising when I am making UI component as docker container using DockerFile

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY prod.nginx.proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY dist/my-webui /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

prod.nginx.proxy.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name frontend;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8443/;
  }
}
```

Command I using to build and run as docker container:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t my-webui .
docker run -d -p 80:80 my-webui
```

`http://localhost:80/` **is launching the angular index pages but not able to fetch the backend data** , I am guessing some issue with the nginx configuration. Please help to find equivalent `nginx config` for my `proxy.config.json`

Error is `502 Bad Gateway` and also It is making http `POST` call to `http://localhost/api/user/authenticate` rather `http://localhost:8443/api/user/authenticate`, also for FYI in header I can see `Remote Address: [::1]:80` instead of `Remote Address: 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how docker networking works. To communicate between them using localhost (which you do in the proxy_pass), you need to change default networking. I'm no expert but I believe you need to set networking to host on both container for this to work.

When connecting multiple containers, I usually go with docker-compose there you can use the name of the service as hostname in the other containers.

Answer (score 0):

This `prod.nginx.proxy.conf` resolved my issue. But yes I should have used docker compose for networking. This may be a solution for manual prod deployment.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name frontend;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.3:8443;
  }
}
```